# Time interval query order by date

Tags: php, mysql, database

Here is my query i am retrieving birthday list from database using this query i want to retrieve data in asc order  by dob(date of birth) i am using  `order by dob asc` but its giving mysql syntax error.

### **QUERY**

```
SELECT * FROM  members 
WHERE  DATE_ADD(dob, INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(dob) YEAR) 
BETWEEN CURDATE() 
AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY 
ORDER BY dob ASC
```

its working now here is one problem again the dob(date of birth) format is 1990-10-11 when i am using order by dob asc its short the data 1990-10-11 , 1991-10-09, but i want to short this by data not year like 1991-10-09, 1990-10-11

Comment: you forgot to close `)` before order by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this you are missing `)` in your query

```
"SELECT * FROM  members WHERE  DATE_ADD(dob, INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(dob) YEAR) BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) order by date(dob) asc"
```

if you wan to sort by month than use `order by Month(dob)`

You can also try with selected field something like this

```
'SELECT field1, field2, DATE_FORMAT(dob, "%d-%M-%Y") AS userdob FROM  members WHERE  
 DATE_ADD(dob, INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(dob) YEAR) BETWEEN CURDATE() AND 
 DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) order by userdob asc'
```

Comment: its working now here is one problem again the dob(date of birth) format is 1990-10-11 when i am using order by dob asc its short the   data 1990-10-11 , 1991-10-09, but i want to short this by data not year like  1991-10-09, 1990-10-11

Comment: its not working and i also tried this 
SELECT * FROM  members WHERE  DATE_ADD(dob, INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(dob) YEAR) BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%m/%d/%Y') ASC  its working on 7 days interval but i give 30 days interval its not working

Comment: I feel earlier your query was working fine, you just have issue with sort by date only?

Comment: yes query is working fine but i want to shot the list using date or month like 1990-09-10, 1990-09-11, 1980-09-14, 1981-10-01

Comment: to sort by month need to add `Month(dob)`

Comment: I have updated my answer can you try with other query

Answer (score 0):

You missed a )

`...BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY order by...`